# SQL Server : select when record is 1 then return line else return the 0 record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need a little help with a query.

I have written a script that brings back an order number and the number of containers needed (code below):

```
SELECT
    CONI.CONTNO,
    CONI.ITEMNO,
    CONI.[WEIGHT],
    CONI.QTY,
    STOK.PGROUP,
    CASE WHEN CPRO.TNTCOL = 1 THEN 1
         WHEN CPRO.TNTCOL = 0 THEN 0
         WHEN CPRO.TNTCOL IS NULL THEN 0 END AS [TNT],
    CONI.RECID,
    CPRO.RECKEY
INTO
    #SUB
FROM
    ContItems CONI
LEFT JOIN 
    ContractItemProfiles CPRO ON CONI.RECID = CPRO.RECKEY
JOIN 
    Stock STOK ON CONI.ITEMNO = STOK.ITEMNO
WHERE
    STOK.PGROUP LIKE 'FLI%'


SELECT
    #SUB.CONTNO,
    #SUB.TNT,
    SUM(#SUB.QTY) AS [Number of flight cases]
FROM
    #SUB
WHERE
    #SUB.CONTNO = '123/321581'
GROUP BY
    #SUB.CONTNO,
    #SUB.TNT

DROP TABLE #SUB
```

I get this result:

```
Contno      TNT    Number of flight cases
------------------------------------------
123/321581   0     20.00
123/321581   1      1.00
```

I need to conditionally bring back the line that has the TNT = 1 Else if there isn't a 1 in the TNT column then bring back the record with 0

I hope this is explained enough.

Comment: Will a `TOP 1 ... ORDER BY #SUB.TNT DESC` help? If not, you can do 2 selects, the first one filtering by `TNT = 1` and the second one only if `@@ROWCOUNT = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

That case can be replaced with

```
isnull(CPRO.TNTCOL, 0) 


select top 1 
from ( SELECT #SUB.CONTNO,
              #SUB.TNT,
              SUM(#SUB.QTY) AS [Number of flight cases]
         FROM #SUB
        WHERE #SUB.CONTNO = '123/321581'
     ) t 
order by TNT desc
```

Comment: @TitoPaterson Did that not answer your question?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try this yet. I've got a few other projects on the go. I will let you know once I have tried this.